# Windows 7 - permissions on shared folder and sub folder

Tags: windows-7, permissions, network-shares

I have a small network of windows 7 computers on a LAN.
I have a scenario with the following folder structure

- Parent Folder A

  - Sub Folder X
  - Sub Folder Y

I want to share out folder A as Read/write by everyone. Then on other computers I can do "map network drive" to it. Let's say I map this to N:/
I want to share out Sub Folder X as Read-only by everyone. Then on other computers I can do "map network drive" but when X is accessed via this path the folder and files are read-only. Let's say I map this to P:/.

**I got this to work in XP** but for some reason it does not work in Win 7. What happens is that when I access P:/ the share is read-only as expected. When I try to access to access N:/ every folder except Sub Folder X is read/write. Sub folder X is read-only.

On the host computer, if i right click X -> properties -> security, I can see that the behaiour is correct (i.e. everyone only has "read&execute" and does not have "Full Control")

Does anyone know how i can get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, probably need more information here. What are the two client computers you are trying to connect? What OS are they using? I assume you are using a workgroup and not a domain?

Comment: all the computers are windows 7. they are all part of the same homegroup and workgroup.